# prevent org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException print stack trace

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, java-websocket

i am currently writing a websocket project using spring boot. And i have a websocket authentication config as this:

```
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
public class WebSocketAuthenticationConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(new ChannelInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
                if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
                    List<String> authorization = accessor.getNativeHeader("X-Authorization");
                    if (authorization.size() > 0) {
                        if (authorization.get(0).equals("hack")) {
                            throw new MessagingException("Invalid token");
                        } else {
                            accessor.setUser(new StompPrincipal(authorization.get(0)));
                        }
                    }
                }
                return message;
            }
        });
    }


}
```

as you can see, i throw a messagingException inside configureClientInboundChannel method.
The problem is this exception keep print stack trace in console like this:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Invalid token
    at com.school.chatbox.config.WebSocketAuthenticationConfig$1.preSend(WebSocketAuthenticationConfig.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel$ChannelInterceptorChain.applyPreSend(AbstractMessageChannel.java:178) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:132) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:122) ~[spring-messaging-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler.handleMessageFromClient(StompSubProtocolHandler.java:302) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(SubProtocolWebSocketHandler.java:335) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:75) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:56) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:58) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.AbstractSockJsSession.delegateMessages(AbstractSockJsSession.java:384) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.session.WebSocketServerSockJsSession.handleMessage(WebSocketServerSockJsSession.java:195) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.transport.handler.SockJsWebSocketHandler.handleTextMessage(SockJsWebSocketHandler.java:93) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.AbstractWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(AbstractWebSocketHandler.java:43) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.handleTextMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:114) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.access$000(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:43) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$3.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:82) ~[spring-websocket-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.sendMessageText(WsFrameBase.java:395) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.sendMessageText(WsFrameServer.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataText(WsFrameBase.java:495) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:294) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:133) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:82) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.doOnDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.notifyDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:151) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:148) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:59) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

is there any solution for me to prevent the print stack trace. Thank you

Comment: Are you catching this exception anywhere in your application ?

Comment: @Datta2811 Catching this exception is what i want. But i dont know how to catch it.

Comment: Not sure about particular web socket project but as you are using Spring boot you should be able to write exception handler for the application.

Comment: @ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerControllerAdvice {

 @ExceptionHandler(MessagingException.class)

Comment: What stopping you from writing exception handler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is a bit old, but I faced the same problem and found a workaround.

After debugging, I noticed its the StompSubProtocolHandler who prints this stack trace on the console:

```
        ...
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            if (logger.isErrorEnabled()) {
                logger.error("Failed to send client message to application via MessageChannel" +
                        " in session " + session.getId() + ". Sending STOMP ERROR to client.", ex);
            }
            handleError(session, ex, message);
        }
        ...
```

So I just set the logging level of the class to OFF. Just put this on application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.StompSubProtocolHandler=OFF
```

Note that this will hide **ALL errors** from StompSubProtocolHandler.

In my case this is not a problem because all of StompSubProtocolHandler's errors are connection problems caused by clients bad internet connection.